# Dynamic Time Analysis using PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, datetime, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose we have a dataset with the following structure:

```
df = sc.parallelize([['a','2015-11-27', 1], ['a','2015-12-27',0], ['a','2016-01-29',0], ['b','2014-09-01', 1], ['b','2015-05-01', 1] ]).toDF(("user", "date", "category"))
```

What I want to analyze is the users' attributes with regard to their lifetime in months. For example, I want to sum up the column "category" for each month of a user's lifetime. For user 'a', this would look like:

```
output = sc.parallelize([['a',0, 1], ['a',1,0], ['a',2,0]]).toDF(("user", "user_lifetime_in_months", "sum(category)"))
```

What is the most efficient way in Spark to do that? E.g., window functions?